# How fast can you Move an Object?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

This came up in another question, although I can't remember if it was here, or in another location.

When using [Move Object](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/move-object-control/), how fast can you move the object?

The long range of Move Object is rank x 100 feet. The text implies you can throw objects, freely, which suggests that at Rank 10, you could throw a 200 pound human a mile without much trouble.

Should someone with Move Object who is standing 1000 feet from their teammate be able to pick up their teammate as a Move action, move them as a Standard (or maybe vice versa), and then drop them as a Free action, another 1000 feet away? What if you have Perception range Move Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post my gut feeling on this, that it is based on Throwing distance. 2E Ultimate Power stated something similar:

> Objects equaling a heavy load or more move at a rate of
> 5 feet per round. Lighter objects move a distance each round like
> they were thrown with your effective Strength. Objects thrown as
> attacks base their damage off your power rank as if it were your
> Strength bonus.

This will be limited by your range if you want to maintain control, although having a maximum distance to be "thrown" that's greater than your effective control radius might still come into play if you can't take a straight path (although then, it becomes even more important to have Precise and an Accurate sense to track what you're moving), and you'll still face distance penalties.

And this was confirmed by Steve Kenson in [the *Mutants and Masterminds Monday* podcast on 2023-Nov-20](https://www.youtube.com/live/UR0wrUeuypE?si=bA-GZDsP_VDqJcP6).